# Saving 'this' in Javascript before async call

Tags: javascript

I just got started in Javascript, backbone, and jquery.  My coworker was trying to explain the this concept and contexts in Javascript.  He was saying this type of pattern is common, but there might be better ways to do it.  I was wondering if it is in fact the "standard" pattern or if there was a better way.

Basically, the pattern is, when I'm in my class that is handling what's being viewed on screen (for us, it's a combination of MVC and backbone), I need to fetch my data to populate the page.  But before we fetch, we do

```
var _this = this;
```

Since the ajax call we do is asynch, he was saying that if in our success handler, if we did

```
this.model.property = // set some property from the callback
```

this would not be what we want and we need to do

```
_this.model.property = // something
```

I guess I was wondering if this is pretty standard.  I feel like after a week of Javascript, I'm doing it every time I fetch data from the server, and sometimes before I try to format my page with underscore's _.each since I guess 'this' changes in my _.each block as well.  Thanks!

Comment: You can also use _.bind to bind this in functions but as your co worker says it's a pretty common pattern in js to store the this object.

Comment: this is a standard. Just be sure `_this` variable is only a block variable so it's garbage collected when it's not used anymore

Answer (score 1):

Scope is one of the most tricky parts of javascript, basically, that is what your friend is describing. Fully understanding scope is the key to being awesome at javascript. Check out some of these links for a full understanding of what is occuring:

1. [Mozilla Article on Functions and Scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope)
2. [Another good article](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/)

Anyways, I hope you like javascript, its personally my favorite language, especially after node.js found its way into my life :)

Edit:

To actually answer your question: What is happening is that the context is becoming lost in the async mode, and so the scope of `this` changes. Saving it off allows you to reference it later. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can bind function to context, so during async call you don't have to use annoying

```
var _this = this
//or
var self = this;
```

You can use underscore.js bind function:

```
//this - current context
var func = function ({ this.doSomething(); });
var bindedFunction = _.bind(func, this);
```

So when you call bindedFunction it will be bound to the currentContext.

If you are using backbone, usually I bind callback functions, so they'r bound to the object:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function (args) {
            _.bindAll(this, 'onDataFetched'); 
        },
        fetchData: function () {
            $.ajax({
            //... some code
                success: this.onDataFetched
            });
        },
        onDataFetched: function(result) {
            //Do something usefull here
            //this = MyView instance
        }
});
```